# lsblk + print only disks that with specific size

Tags: linux, awk, sed, hard-disk, lsblk

I want to print all disks that are equal or more then 18G
how to fit the following syntax in order to print only the disks that are => 18G

```
lsblk -l  | awk '/disk/'

fd0            2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda            8:0    0   150G  0 disk
sdb            8:16   0    20G  0 disk 
sdc            8:32   0    20G  0 disk 
sdd            8:48   0    20G  0 disk 
sde            8:64   0    20G  0 disk 
sdf            8:80   0    20G  0 disk 
sdg            8:96   0    20G  0 disk
sdh            8:112  0    20G  0 disk
sdi            8:128  0    20G  0 disk
sdj            8:144  0    2G   0 disk
sdk            8:160  0    2G   0 disk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`lsblk`** + **`awk`** + **`numfmt`** solution:

```
lsblk -lnb | awk '$4>=19327352832' | numfmt --to=iec --field=4
```

---

**`lsblk`** options:

- `-n` - do not print a header line
- `-b` - print the SIZE column in bytes rather than in a human-readable format

**`awk`** details:

- `$4` - the 4th field value(`SIZE` column)
- `19327352832` - equivalent to `18G` in byte units

**`numfmt`** options:

- `--to=iec` - auto-scale output numbers to `UNITs`; accept optional single letter suffix: `1K = 1024, 1M = 1048576, ...`
- `--field=<FIELDS>` - replace/transform the numbers in these input fields `FIELDS`

Comment: how you calculate the value - 19327352832? for 18G ?

Comment: `18 * 1024 = 18432MB`; `18432 * 1024 = 18874368KB`; `18874368 * 1024 = 19327352832B`.  Google can't be trusted for byte conversions anymore because the went all metric and to them 1KB = 1000 Bytes and they have added a KiB which is equal to 1024 bytes, but even that system often gives me inaccuracies.

Comment: @Jesse_b - google is a search engine, "they" don't do any conversions and as long as you don't mistake [SI units for IEC units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Systematic_multiples) there should be no inaccuracy.

Comment: @don_crissti, fair enough but I still want to rag on google for it because their conversions used to be IEC only and now they default to SI.  The wiki you linked says: "There have been many attempts to resolve the confusion by providing alternative notations for power-of-two multiples."  But in my opinion every effort to resolve this confusion only adds to it.  I don't see a need for the SI standard when referring to data sizes.

Comment: @Jesse_b - that's also very true...

Answer (score 0):

My `lsblk` doesn't work, but does this work for you?

```
lsblk -l | awk '{
    if ($4~/.*G/ && $4/1 >= 18) || 
       ($4~/.*T/)
       print $0;
    }'

#As a single line:
lsblk -l | awk '{if ($4~/.*G/ && $4/1 >= 18) || ($4~/.*T/){print $0}}'
```

`awk` program

- `$4~/.*G/` is matching any pattern in field 4 ending in `G`
- `$4/1 >= 18` if it ends in `G`, divide it by `1` (to remove the G) and check if it's greater than or equal to `18`
- `$4~/.*T/` or if it the string in field 4 ends in `T` it passes.

**Note:**
RomanPerekhrest's solution is more robust.